# Spring Boot Repository.save() methods do not work - No commit

Tags: java, android-studio, spring-boot, qr-code

I scan two QR code and try to get them from My QR Code Android Mobile App and save it with `repository.save()` in my Local db.

My app send List to Backend but don't insert to db. When I run **localhost/8090**, i don't get back anything.
In Browser show only this:

-Find Devices
-Device Code
-Device ID

**`Developer.java`**

```
@Entity
public class Developer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id = 0;
    private String deviceCode;
    private String deviceId;
    public Developer() {
        super();
    }

    public Developer(String deviceCode, String deviceID)
             {
        super();
        this.deviceCode = deviceCode;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String deviceCode() {
        return deviceCode;
    }

    public void set DeviceCode(String deviceCode) {
        this.deviceCode;
    }

    public String deviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void set DeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId;
    }

}
```

**`DeveloperRepository.java`**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DeveloperRepository extends CrudRepository<Developer, Long> {

}
```

**`DeveloperController.java`**

```
@Controller
public class DevelopersController {

    @Autowired
    DeveloperRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    private String addDevices(Developer deviceCodeAndId) {
        System.out.println("xyz!");

        if (!repository.exists(deviceCodeAndId.getId())) {
            repository.save(deviceCodeAndId);
            return "successfully added " +     deviceCodeAndId.getId();
        }
        return deviceCodeAndId.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showall",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("index",repository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

`deviceCodeAndID` is Class from Android App which scanned with app!

```
index.html
```

Comment: Sorry for GET SET, I wrote wrong. Problem is not there!

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled transaction management. Even you use Spring boot data repository. You need to enable transaction management, else by default everything will be read mode. And for read mode there is no need to transaction. But when you do any operation that will change data in DB, you need to perform transaction management. 
Use `@EnableTransactionManagement` on in application class, and `@Transactional` in DAO or service class

Comment: Thanks for Quick Answer but i dont have DAO or service class. I dont need both or i need Them? I try it.

Comment: Try adding below annotations on your application class. 
`@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan("entity_package")
@EnableJpaRepositories("Repository_package")`

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    DeveloperRepository developerRepository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Here is my Application Class